# Authentication issue in Codemagic while building for iOS with flutter

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, codemagic

I was trying to build and upload my flutter app and this error came out with 10 attempts of upload in the Publishing step, have no idea why that could be. The iOS Sign In it´s actually conected and also the App Store Connect, the app build goes smoothly

Here´s the error in question:

```
Failed to upload archive, but this might be a temporary issue, retrying...
Attempt #2 to upload failed, retrying...
Attempt #3 to upload failed, retrying...
Attempt #4 to upload failed, retrying...
Attempt #5 to upload failed, retrying...
Attempt #6 to upload failed, retrying...
Attempt #7 to upload failed, retrying...
Attempt #8 to upload failed, retrying...
Attempt #9 to upload failed, retrying...
Attempt #10 to upload failed.
*** status code 401, auth issue.



{"tool-version":"4.071.1221","tool-path":"\/Applications\/Xcode-13.2.1.app\/Contents\/SharedFrameworks\/ContentDeliveryServices.framework\/Versions\/A\/Frameworks\/AppStoreService.framework","os-version":"11.6.2","product-errors":[{"message":"Unable to authenticate.","userInfo":{"NSLocalizedDescription":"Unable to authenticate.","NSLocalizedFailureReason":"Unable to authenticate."},"code":-19209}]}

Failed to publish to App Store Connect.
```

tysm

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too, but after retrying the build several times without changing anything in particular, I was successful. Perhaps a few retries might help you succeed.